# zsh generate autocompletion options from `--help`

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

My goal is to generate `zsh` completions for a program I am writing. One option would be to write a lengthy completion file that lists all arguments and options, but since I often add arguments and options I would love `zsh` to handle the generation of the completions by itself. My program has a `--help` argument that provides output similar to this:

```
$ myProgram --help
Usage: myProgram
Lorem ipsum

Possible Arguments:
    --argOps                 Description of argOps that takes options. Possible Values: [foo, bar, baz]
    --argNoOps               Description of argNoOps.
    --argFiles               Description of argFiles that says it takes a file path. 

myProgram documentation is available via: ...
```

From this `zsh` is able to generate something in the general direction of what I want with the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
compdef _gnu_generic myProgram    # parses arguments from 'myProgram --help'
```

However, I want more: If I for example write `myProgram --argOps` and hit tab `zsh` should present me with the options for `argOps` namely `foo` `bar` and `baz` and also allow completion on those. In theory, this should be possible by parsing the output of `myProgram --help` since all the information is available there. I tried writing a custom completion script following the [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System). There, I noticed the subsection "Deriving spec forms from the help output" which talks about the form `_arguments --` that allows pattern matching on the output of `--help`. However, it seems that one can only match the arguments themselves and not the description texts?

If I could access the descriptions I would not mind writing weird regex parsers, but I am a bit lost in how to access the descriptions.

Note: Since this is my own program I can completely change the output of `--help` if necessary.

Comment: Rather than generating the completions from the help output, have your program itself output the completions using `myProgram --zsh-completions`. Then your program is responsible for generating two different outputs from the same underlying data structure that contains the necessary information.

Comment: I like the idea and am tempted to use it as a temporary solution, but I still would like to know how to achieve the above.